# Template constructor, and creating an object in main class

Tags: java, templates, constructor

This is how the constructor looks like.

```
public Polinom(ArrayList<Integer> koeficient)
{
    this.koeficienti = koeficienti;
}
```

This is how i create an array and insert the elements.

```
int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

And when i try to create an object like this:

```
Polinom arr3 = new Polinom(arr);
```

It tells me that "The constructor Polinom(int[]) is undefined.
I am quite knew with Java programming language but familiar with c++, 
but i have big problems about the syntax.

Comment: A List is not the same type as an array.  The constructor takes a List (an ArrayList), but `new Polinom(arr)` is attempting to pass an array.  They're different types so not compatible.

Comment: Try to make `arr` an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead. Compare to C++ with a constructor taking a  `std::vector<int>` and sending it an `int *`

Comment: The class was given by my professor with 'Array' instead of 'ArrayList' which was added by me because there was a problem : "Array can not be resolved as a type". So i changed it and made a bigger mess.

Comment: Side note: Java Generics are not templates like C++. Very, very different under the covers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int[]` (an array of `int`) is not an `ArrayList<Integer>` (a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of `Integer`, specifically an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)).

You'd either want to use a `List`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    list.add(input.nextInt());
}
```

where your constructor would be:

```
public Polinom(List<Integer> koeficienti)
{
    // Generally not best practice to just remember the list passed in; instead,
    // make a *defensive copy* of it so this instance doesn't share the list with
    // the caller. (Or accept an immutable list.)
    this.koeficienti = new ArrayList<Integer>(koeficienti);
}
```

**or** write your constructor such that it expects an array:

```
public Polinom(int[] entries)
{
    this.koeficienti = new ArrayList<Integer>(entries.length);
    for (int entry : entries) {
        this.koeficienti.add(entry);
    }
}
```

You may find these official Java tutorials useful:

- [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)